# Preservation of cardinality under ordinal exponentiation.

Tags: set-theory

In Kenneth Kunen's *The Foundations of Mathematics*, he presents the following exercise and hint.

> **Exercise I.11.34** Ordinal arithmetic doesn't raise cardinality. That is, assume that $\alpha$, $\beta$ are ordinals with $2 \leq \text{min}(\alpha,\beta)$ and $\omega \leq \text{max}(\alpha,\beta)$. Then prove that $|\alpha + \beta| = |\alpha \cdot \beta| = |\alpha^\beta| = \text{max}(|\alpha|,|\beta|)$.
>
> **Hint.** For $\alpha + \beta$ and $\alpha \cdot \beta$ this is easy from Theorem I.11.32 and the definition of $+$ and $\cdot$. The proof is slightly tricky for exponentiation, since the natural proof by induction on $\beta$ seems to use the Axiom of Choice (AC). Here, we take the recursive computation in Table I.1 to be the definition of $\alpha^\beta$. Now say we want to prove by induction on $\beta$ that $\alpha^\beta$ is countable whenever $\alpha, \beta$ are countable. If $\beta$ is a limit, we have $\alpha^\beta = \text{sup}_{\xi < \beta}(\alpha^\xi) = \bigcup_{\xi < \beta} (\alpha^\xi)$ which (applying induction) is a countable union of countable sets. But the well-known fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable uses AC. To avoid AC first fix a $\delta < \omega_1$ and then fix an $f: \delta \xrightarrow{1-1} \omega$. Now, we may now define, for $\alpha,\beta<\delta$, an injection from $\alpha^\beta$ into $\omega$; the definition uses $f$, and is done by recursion on $\beta$; the definition also uses a (fixed) injection from $\omega \times \omega$ into $\omega$.

I finished proving that $|\alpha + \beta| = |\alpha \cdot \beta| = \text{max}(|\alpha|, |\beta|)$ without issue. I'm stuck on following the hint for exponentiation. Usually I find the hints clear, but this time I'm confused. We are defining a function based off an injection from $\alpha^\beta$ into $\omega$ by recursion on $\beta$. I don't exactly follow the construction. I'm also wondering, this hint only gives the case that we are assuming that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are countable. What about ordinals of arbitrary cardinality that satisfy the above conditions? Is it just a small modification of the argument we use for the countable case?

Answer (score 2):

Prove this by induction on $\beta$.

1. $\alpha^2$ is $\alpha\cdot\alpha$, so you are back to multiplication.
2. $\alpha^{\gamma+1}=\alpha^\gamma\cdot\alpha$, by the induction hypothesis that's the same cardinality as $\alpha\cdot\alpha$, so we are back to multiplication again.
3. If $\beta$ is limit, then $\alpha^\beta=\sup\{\alpha^\gamma\mid \gamma<\beta\}$. Then either $\beta>\alpha$ is a cardinal, in which case $|\alpha^\gamma|<\beta$, and so $\alpha^\beta=\beta$. Or else we have a uniform way of enumerating $\alpha^\gamma$ for all $\gamma<\beta$. This means that we get an injection into $\max(\alpha,\beta)\times\beta$, so we're done.

   Or, if you don't mind using AC, just apply it judiciously to get $\max\{\alpha,\beta\}$ again.

Answer (score 0):

Asaf's answer is good enough. Just to make this clearer, at the limit step, we define the injection $f: \alpha^\beta \to \max(\alpha,\beta)$ as follows:

$$f(x)=\Gamma(\delta,f_\delta(x)) \text{ where $\delta\in \beta$ is the smallest ordinal for which $x\in \alpha^{\delta}$ and $\Gamma$ is a paring function}.$$

This function is clearly injective (the first argument here is needed or else $f_\delta(x)$ could be equal to $f_\sigma(y)$ where $\delta\neq \sigma $ and $x\neq y$).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof that follows Kunen's hint.

Let $\max\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\}=\kappa$. Fix ordinal $\delta$, s.t. $\delta>\alpha$, $\delta>\beta$ and $|\delta|=\kappa$ (e.g. $\delta=\max\{\alpha,\beta\}+1$).

Fix bijections $f\colon \delta \to \kappa$ and $\Gamma \colon \kappa \times \kappa \to \kappa$. We define injections $i_{\gamma} \colon \alpha^{\gamma} \to \kappa$ for all $\gamma \in \delta$ recursively.

1. $\gamma=0$. Define $i_0(\emptyset)=\emptyset$.
2. $\gamma=\sigma+1$. Let $h \colon \alpha^{\sigma} \cdot \alpha \to \alpha^{\sigma} \times \alpha$ be the canonical order isomorphism. $\forall \eta \in \alpha^{\gamma}$, we define $i_{\gamma}(\eta)=\Gamma(i_{\delta}(h_1(\eta)),f(h_2(\eta)))$.
3. $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal. $\forall \eta \in \alpha^{\gamma}$, let $\delta < \gamma$ be the least ordinal s.t. $\eta \in \alpha^{\delta}$, and define $i_{\gamma}(\eta) = \Gamma(i_{\sigma}(\eta),f(\sigma))$.

In particular, this gives an injection $i_{\beta}$ from $\alpha^{\beta}$ to $\kappa$, so $|\alpha^{\beta}| \leq \kappa$. It is not difficult to prove the other direction.